# XBAP download fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: internet-explorer, xbap

At the very end of `XBAP` download I got the error trace below. I already tried to figure out what's missing using `Procmon` and `VS2013-debugger`. However, I didn't succeed so far... Any hints??

```
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [23.05.2014 12:55:03] System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateActContext(CreateActContextParameters& Params)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateActContext(IDefinitionAppId AppId)
            at System.ActivationContext.CreateFromName(ApplicationIdentity applicationIdentity)
            at System.ActivationContext.CreatePartialActivationContext(ApplicationIdentity identity)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()
```

In Fidder I got 200s for all files downloaded...

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue was the default limit of the cache-size which is 250MB. Here's what I had to do:

Add/change`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\OnlineAppQuotaInKB`, which is a `DWORD` value that expresses the cache size in kilobytes. For example, in order to increase the cache size to 500MB, I set this value to 512000.